# Include java classes on SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, sapui5

I want to include some java classes on my sapui5 project created on eclipse using javascript. I have this code

**exampe1.view.js**

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    return new sap.m.Page({
        title: "Title",
        content: [
            new sap.m.Button({text:"Click here",
                press: function(){
                    alert("ok")
                }
            })
        ]
    });
}
```

on button "Click here" press I want to call a java method.  How to do that?
 I have already imported all my classes on the folder named **src**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a REST service in which you need to write your Java code. From SAPUI5 application you can call this REST service hosted and running on server (Tomcat, SAP Netweaver etc ) .
Calling can be done by making AJAX call to the Url of REST service / Servlet and passing parameters if any in that ajax call.

Importing Java class files is not enough since you need something to execute the code written in Java which is why you need to host your code as a servlet or REST service ( eg. using Jersey framework).
SAPUI5 is simply a Javascript library and so doesnt understand Java code directly.